# Spring App is not getting deployed after upgrading to Spring6 and Tomcat10

Tags: java, spring, tomcat10

I am upgrading a Spring 5.x app to Spring.6 and trying to deploy to Tomcat 10(apache-tomcat-10.1.15) (Older app was getting deployed to apache-tomcat-9.0.62)

I did the following changes as part of the Spring 6 upgrade.

- Updated all the spring versions to 6.0.11
- Changed all the javax.* dependencies to jakarta.*
- Updated Hibernate to latest version.
- Did everything mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html

I am getting below error while deploying to Tomcat 10.

```
30-Oct-2023 14:47:39.081 WARNING [main] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in MyWebSecurityConfig: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
30-Oct-2023 14:47:39.085 SEVERE [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in MyWebSecurityConfig: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:825)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:778)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:394)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4860)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1952)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1659)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in MyWebSecurityConfig: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:647)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1375)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:817)
    ... 57 more
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    ... 73 more
  Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext.getServletRegistrations(StandardContext.java:6197)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.mappableServletRegistrations(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:276)
    MyWebSecurityConfig.lambda$filterChain$1(WebSecurityConfig.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.authorizeHttpRequests(HttpSecurity.java:1466)
    MyWebSecurityConfig.filterChain(WebSecurityConfig.java:64)
    MyWebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$filterChain$7(<generated>)
    MyWebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    MyWebSecurityConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.filterChain(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
```